# How to get ConnectedApp details using REST API

Tags: rest-api, tooling-api

How to retrieve connected app information using rest/tooling api?

Comment: well, it is possible to get some of the information by using SOQL query from ConnectedApplication object, however, not sure if that would answer your question

Comment: well, it is possible to get some of the information by using SOQL query from ConnectedApplication object, however, not sure if that would answer your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't. [ConnectedApp](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm) settings are only available in the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/). You'll need to learn a bit of SOAP in order to get at the data.